# To shuffle six characters and print the permutation of an array

Tags: java, permutation, shuffle

I am trying to print the array of characters by shuffling them. I saw other posts as well but wish to come up with my own naive algorithm. Here is the code :

```
public class Carbon{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Char A = new Char[6] {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<6;j++) {
                if(i<=j) {
                    for (int k=i;k<=j;k++)
                        System.out.print(A[k]);
                }
                else{
                    for (int k=i;k>=j;k--)
                        System.out.print(A[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following errors occurred :

```
 Carbon.java:3: error: ';' expected
        Char A = new Char[6] {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
                            ^
Carbon.java:3: error: not a statement
        Char A = new Char[6] {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
                              ^
Carbon.java:3: error: ';' expected
        Char A = new Char[6] {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
                                 ^
3 errors
```

I brainstormed more than 1 hour to debug but failed. Please help.

Comment: In which line is the error shown?

Comment: I get compiler errors within Line 3,4,9,14 and none of them is the error you get. Did you post the whole content of the file?

Comment: @VikranthInti Re-read [user2762451's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32177895/3558960). Replace the two incorrect lines you have (declaration and initialization of A) with the line user2762451 specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to `char[] a = new char[]{'c', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'o', 'n'};`
It's a little clumsy to access individual characters if you use the `String` type.

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly commited the change u mentioned into the original post instead of replying the changed code to your answer. Feels really naive.

Answer (score 1):

You have severals issues here.

- Char is used for a class named "Char", if you want to use the primitive type, the name as to be in lower case "char"

So in your case:

```
Char A = new Char[6] {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
```

has to become

```
char A = new char[6] {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
```

But still now it does not work because you are trying to bind a unique char to an array of char

So here again, code has to be fixed to:

```
char[] A = new char[6] {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
```

Now there is the last problem, you have a new array and a static array at the same time. So either you set your variable "A" (for which the name should be lower case as per convention) either you assign the static array.

Let's stick with the second option and you code becomes:

```
char[] A = {'c','a','r','b','o','n'};
```

And now it works

Output will be :
ccacarcarbcarbocarbonacaararbarboarbonracrarrbrborbonbracbrabrbbobonobracobraobroboonnobracnobranobrnobnon